# how can i Select data from database using input type box and print on same page

Tags: php, mysql, database

THIS IS MY CODE HERE I AM GETTING PROBLEM THIS IS A INPUT TYPE TAG AND NOT SELECTED DATA FROM DATABASE USING PHP.
here is first part of this code is html formatted ad second part is php 
i want select data from database to data slect to same page as we see on the sopping cart sites

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>phpSelect</title>
</head>
<body>
Insert Age for search
<form action="#" method="post" >
<input type="text" id="val" name="resValue" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"  /></form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $res=$_POST['resValue'];

    echo $res;
    }
//echo $res;
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons where Age=25");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to change your select to take the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the SQL to this

`SELECT * FROM Persons where Age='".mysql_escape_string($formValue['val'])."'`

Answer (score 0):

Change your select query to this one.

```
SELECT * FROM Persons where Age='".mysql_escape_string($_POST['val'])."'
```

Comment: Could you add some extra information about how your code works?

Answer (score 0):

First issue I found on your code is here:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit"  />
```

it should be:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

To be able to get the results. Below are the codes:

```
<?php
$query = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $res=$_POST['resValue'];
  $query = " where Age='$res'"
}
//echo $res;
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons $query");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your problem the all value of form get by the name of all fields of form.\
    so here should be

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

Because in $_POST['submit'] submit is same as button's name.
```

Answer (score 0):

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons where Age="25");